# Why is yum still using epel 5? Cent OS 6

Tags: linux, mcrypt, centos6, server-configuration

Trying to install mcrypt on CentOS 6.

After reading other posts, I learned that yum was using epel 5, when it needed to use epel 6.

So, I removed epel:

```
$ yum remove epel-release
```

And got epel 6:

```
$ wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

My epel.repo file looks like:

```
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

Everything pointing to epel 6...right?

Well, with `$ yum install php-mcrypt`, this error is thrown:

```
Package: php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Requires: php-api = 20041225
```

Still pulling from Epel 5?  What's going on...and how can I get yum to use Epel 6 instead?

Comment: For openers, run yum clean all first.  Also make sure you don't see epel5 in yum repolist.

Comment: yum clean all fixed it - thanks